# Quick regex with alert

Tags: javascript, regex

I wish to allow only numbers and periods ( but only one period ) no commas, no alpha.

So user can type 300.00

I also need to trigger alert, if possible ( not a windows alert just a   alert )

I have :

```
**<input maxlength="12" type="text" name="r" id="price" style="display:none;width:212px;margin-left:5px;border-color:#F12B63;" size="30" placeholder="Type your price numbers only" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/\D+/, '')" />**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the regular expression, try this: `^\d+\.?\d+$`.

It will match a string which starts with one or more digits, optionally followed by a single period, which is then followed by one or more digits which form the end of the string.

To test the value, within your validation code do this:

```
//Add event handler using W3C event binding
document.getElementById("price").addEventListener("blur", function()
{
   //Test the value of the input field and whether it matches the regular expression,     where val is the value extracted from the field
  if(!this.value.match(/^\d+\.?\d+$/))
  {
    alert("Validation error, must be numeric");
  }
}, false);
```

EDIT: note that if you wish to add event binding in IE you can either use traditional event binding `document.getElementById("price").onblur = function(){...}` or IE's event binding model: `document.getElementById("price").attachEvent("onblur", function(){...});` note though that using `attachEvent` does not assign the this object within the callback function, so you will need to get the event object (`window.event`) and then extract the element using `window.event.srcElement`. See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html for reference

Comment: how do i add listener to the input field using that, ?

Comment: The period character needs to be escaped.  Your regex will match 300x00 or 300q00.

Comment: Cheers I really am thick as pig shit, fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/uqMk7/2/

Comment: @jfriend00 you are correct, changed code. Knew I had made a mistake somewhere. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: Cheers anyway guys, I am totally lost. No idea what to do, will accept answer and keep on trucking thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I guess`var result=this.value.match(/[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+/); if(result==null){alert}`