# Limit input tag only for specific word or number

Tags: javascript, html, input, limit

I have an input tag `<input maxlength="2" />`

I want to limit input for tag above, just for number `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` only

Is anyone know how to do something like that?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Answer can be found here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936018/limit-input-to-numbers-and-on-input-field

Comment: use javascript for validation

Comment: You can use JavaScript to do client side checking, but you'll still need to double check on the server side.

Comment: here are some good input patterns to search: http://html5pattern.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without javascript, just:

```
  <input type="text" name="fieldname" pattern="10|[1-9]" title="Only 1-10">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp